# Is the state transition of Markov's decision process related to the action?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I know that when Markov Property is satisfied, the next state is only related to the current state. But in the Markov Decision Process(MDP), we need to choose an action and execute it to make that transition. Does this mean that state transitions are related to the chosen action and not just to the state?
And does this situation violate the property of Markov?

Most reinforcement learning is based on MDP.If in MDP, we consider the chosen action is a factor in Markov Property, so in AlphaGo, the next state is not just related to current state and chosen action, It is also affected by opponent's action. Does Go-game satisfy the Markov Property? Does the reinforcement learning algorithm not require the environment to fully satisfy Markov Property? Very confusing.

If in Go-game, we still consider the state transition is related just about the current state, then there is no problem.

Does Go game satisfy Markov Property?
Does the chosen action in MDP is a impact factor between transition?
Does the RL algorithm(based MDP, not POMDP) not require the environment to fully satisfy Markov Property?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the algorithm that has the Markov property. The Markov property is a property of the problem setup, and it's depending on what states you use.

But yes, in a MDP the state transition depends not only on the current state, but also on the action taken by the controller. But it does not depend on any earlier states. That's the Markov property.

Once you are in a given state, it doesn't matter how you got there. The current state contains all the information required to make a prediction or a decision. This simplifies the decision algorithm a lot, because it does not need any memory.

For a MDP to make sense with an opponent, you have to think of the opponent as part of the environment. The opponent makes deterministic (or even randomized) choices, but those choices are only based on the current board state.

Strictly speaking, in Go you also need to avoid the repetition of a previous board positions. So if you use the current board position as your state, the Markov property is violated: you can gain additional relevant knowledge by looking at the past board positions.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I still confuse whether Go is satify Markov Property. And if it has the Markov Property, so is it a MDP problem or POMDP problem?